# My ads were disapproved with DISABLED: third_party_redirect_on_landing_page, what does this mean?

Tags: google-ads-api

my client was told by google that certain of my links are "DISABLED: third_party_redirect_on_landing_page". Two of the links given are:

- http://www.texasvistamedicalcenter.org/
- https://www.saltlakeregional.org/services-directory/emergency-care

One of them effectively redirects to another page, but the other does not:

```
curl -I http://www.texasvistamedicalcenter.org/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
...
curl -I https://www.saltlakeregional.org/services-directory/emergency-care
HTTP/2 200 
...
```

This makes me think that Google probably does not like *some other* URL linking to this page instead of being put directly in the ad.

My websearch for third_party_redirect_on_landing_page turned up empty handed. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect to a domain that's different than the domain in your display URL. The domains in your display url and landing page must be the same.